# How do I print return value of a function?

Tags: go, go-templates

Here is my function definition which returns a string

`"addClassIfActive": func(tab string, ctx *web.Context) string`

I'm trying to print it like this:

`<a href="/home/"{{ printf "%s" addClassIfActive "home" .Context }}>Home</a>`

http response is getting terminated when I'm trying to print.

What am I doing wrong?

Returning a boolean, and then using if works, still I'm curious how to print string returned from a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that `"home"` and `.Context` will be the 3:rd and 4:th argument of `printf` and not the arguments of `addClassIfActive`. The return value of `addClassIfActive` becomes the 2:nd argument for `printf`.

But the solution is simple: **you don't have to use `printf` to print.**

If your function just returns a string, you can simply print it by writing:

```
{{addClassIfActive "home" .Context}}
```

Full working example:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

type Context struct {
    Active bool
}

var templateFuncs = template.FuncMap{
    "addClassIfActive": func(tab string, ctx *Context) string {
        if ctx.Active {
            return tab + " content"
        }

        // Return nothing
        return ""
    },
}

var htmlTemplate = `{{addClassIfActive "home" .Context}}`

func main() {
    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "Context": &Context{true}, // Set to false will prevent addClassIfActive to print
    }

    // We create the template and register out template function
    t := template.New("t").Funcs(templateFuncs)
    t, err := t.Parse(htmlTemplate)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

**Output:**

> home content

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2hjhVMdx4s)

Comment: I did try that, it was printing zgotmplz instead of what function returned

Comment: My mistake, it was unsafe HTML, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765395/why-am-i-seeing-zgotmplz-in-my-go-html-template-output

Comment: Ah, yes. I never reflected on where you tried to output the string. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call functions in templates.

What you *can* do is use [FuncMaps](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs):

**templates.go**

```
var t = template.New("base")
// ParseFiles or ParseGlob, etc.
templateHelpers := template.FuncMap{
        "ifactive":    AddClassIfActive,
    }
    t = t.Funcs(templateHelpers)
```

**your_template.tmpl**

```
...
<span class="stuff">{{ if eq .Context | ifactive }} thing {{ else }} another thing {{ end }}</span>
...
```

I haven't tested this exact syntax, but I am using FuncMaps elsewhere. Make sure to read the [better docs at text/template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#FuncMap) on FuncMaps for more examples.