# Multiple line struct definition

Tags: go

How do I define a struct using more than 1 line?

```
type Page struct {
    Title string
    ContentPath string
}

//this is giving me a syntax error
template := Page{
    Title: "My Title",
    ContentPath: "/some/file/path"
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes for the question?  Are multiline struct literals not idiomatic in Go?

Comment: Maybe because neither the question title nor the question body mentions Go. Just a tag. (That's a sincere guess; I'm not being sarcastic)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're just missing a comma after the second field:

```
template := Page{
    Title: "My Title",
    ContentPath: "/some/file/path",
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and thought it wasn't working, turns out this is the problem  I'm really getting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765395/why-am-i-seeing-zgotmplz-in-my-go-html-template-output

Answer (score 19):

You need to end **all** lines with a comma.

This is because of how semicolons are auto-inserted.

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons

Your current code ends up like

```
template := Page{
    Title: "My Title",
    ContentPath: "/some/file/path";
};
```

Adding the comma gets rid of the incorrect semicolon, but also makes it easier to add new items in the future without having to remember to add the comma above.