# How to get rid of ZgotmplZ from html/template in Golang?

Tags: html, templates, url, go, go-html-template

I'm using Golang in backend. When I render the html using html/templates I'm getting `ZgotmplZ` for URL's.

```
{{if .UserData.GitURL}}
<li>
  <a href="{{.UserData.GitURL}}">
    <i class="icon fa fa-github"></i>
  </a>
</li>
{{end}}
```

I'm using string for GitURL in server side. This URL is `https`. When I looked for solutions some blog suggested to use `safeURL`. So I tried,

```
{{if .UserData.GitURL}}
<li>
  <a href="{{.UserData.GitURL | safeURL}}">
    <i class="icon fa fa-github"></i>
  </a>
</li>
{{end}}
```

But code didn't compile.

Could someone help me with this? Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Make sure the url string is correct. For example it'll output 'ZgotmplZ' if its ` https:` with a space in front instead of `https:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I seeing ZgotmplZ in my Go HTML template output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765395/why-am-i-seeing-zgotmplz-in-my-go-html-template-output)

Answer (score 10):

`ZgotmplZ` is a special value indicating your input was invalid. Quoting from the doc of `html/template`:

> ```
> "ZgotmplZ" is a special value that indicates that unsafe content reached a
> CSS or URL context at runtime. The output of the example will be
>    <img src="#ZgotmplZ">
> If the data comes from a trusted source, use content types to exempt it
> from filtering: URL(`javascript:...`).
> ```

If you want to substitute a **valid** url text, nothing special like like `safeURL` function is needed. If your template execution results in a value like `"#ZgotmplZ"`, that means the URL you wanted to insert is invalid.

See this example:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`<a href="{{.}}"></a>` + "\n"))
t.Execute(os.Stdout, "http://google.com")
t.Execute(os.Stdout, "badhttp://google.com")
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://google.com"></a>
<a href="#ZgotmplZ"></a>
```

You may use a value of type [`template.URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#URL) if you want to use a URL as-is without escaping. Note that in this case the provided value will be used as-is even if it is not a valid URL.

`safeURL` is not some kind of magic or predeclared function that you may use in templates. But you may register your own custom function which returns a `string` url parameter as a value of type `template.URL`:

```
t2 := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "safeURL": func(u string) template.URL { return template.URL(u) },
}).Parse(`<a href="{{. | safeURL}}"></a>` + "\n"))
t2.Execute(os.Stdout, "http://google.com")
t2.Execute(os.Stdout, "badhttp://google.com")
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://google.com"></a>
<a href="badhttp://google.com"></a>
```

**Note:** If you are able to pass in a `template.URL` value directly to the template execution, you do not need to register and use a `safeURL()` custom function:

```
t3 := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`<a href="{{.}}"></a>` + "\n"))
t3.Execute(os.Stdout, template.URL("http://google.com"))
t3.Execute(os.Stdout, template.URL("badhttp://google.com"))
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://google.com"></a>
<a href="badhttp://google.com"></a>
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qy3saHsfl8).