# Golang. html/template. How to put a unquoted string to <script>?

Tags: go, go-html-template

I have a template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="data-user">{{.User}}</script>
```

Where "User" is json string in URL encoding format. Something like

`%7Bdata%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%7D`

But default *html/template* put it inside quotes like

`"%7Bdata%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%7D"`

I tried that stuff from [html/template godoc reference](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#pkg-overview)

    `Context                          {{.}} After
    {{.}}                            O'Reilly: How are &lt;i&gt;you&lt;/i&gt;?
    <a title='{{.}}'>                O&#39;Reilly: How are you?
    <a href="/{{.}}">                O&#39;Reilly: How are %3ci%3eyou%3c/i%3e?
    <a href="?q={{.}}">              O&#39;Reilly%3a%20How%20are%3ci%3e...%3f
    <a onx='f("{{.}}")'>             O\x27Reilly: How are \x3ci\x3eyou...?
    <a onx='f({{.}})'>               "O\x27Reilly: How are \x3ci\x3eyou...?"
    <a onx='pattern = /{{.}}/;'>     O\x27Reilly: How are \x3ci\x3eyou...\x3f`

But I haven't had success. 
Appreciate your help

Comment: I think you should look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382624/how-to-get-rid-of-zgotmplz-from-html-template-in-golang)

Comment: Thank you! I found a tip there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you! I found solution. There are [template.JS](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS) type.
I converted string to template.JS and it works.

See this example:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`<script>{{.}}</script>` + "\n"))
t.Execute(os.Stdout, "%7Bdata%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%7D")
t.Execute(os.Stdout, template.JS("%7Bdata%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%7D"))
```

Output:

```
<script>"%7Bdata%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%7D"</script>
<script>%7Bdata%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%7D</script>
```

Try these on the <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/CKxNMj4ACA)</kbd>.