# Getting ZgotmplZ when sending an email link rendered with html/template to a Slack channel

Tags: go, go-html-template

I' trying to generate a mailto link with an email address as link text `<mailto:{{.user_email }}|{{.user_email}}> has confirmed his email`, which I want to send to a slack channel.

But when I parse the template with the `user_email`, I am getting the output as

```
<mailto:ZgotmplZ|ZgotmplZ> has confirmed his email
```

I know

> "ZgotmplZ" is a special value that indicates that unsafe content reached a
> CSS or URL context at runtime. The output of the example will be
>
> If the data comes from a trusted source, use content types to exempt it
> from filtering: URL(`javascript:...`).

I would like to get an output as

```
 <mailto:john.doe@gmail.com|john.doe@gmail.com> has confirmed his email
```

because this is the template style for sending email [links](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#linking-urls) in slack.

I've tried using a custom template function to escape the values, but the problem persists.

Here is the simplified version of my code

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {

    emailTemplate := `<mailto:{{.user_email }}|{{.user_email}}> has confirmed his email`

    tmpl, err := template.
        New("emailTemplate").
        Parse(emailTemplate)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "user_email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    err = tmpl.Execute(&buf, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly render the email address in the template without it being treated as unsafe or displaying `ZgotmplZ` instead

Comment: @mkopriva It's here https://pkg.go.dev/html/template and also at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382624/how-to-get-rid-of-zgotmplz-from-html-template-in-golang

Comment: It's not a solution, but I noticed that removing the leading `<` character from the template string causes the data input to work properly. [Here's that code running in Playground.](https://go.dev/play/p/SuBOZna7vuQ).